# How can I send notifications to my android app users automatically?

Tags: android, json, notifications, android-volley

I am developing a news app that uses JSON data from a URL using volley. I want to send notifications to my users everytime a new article is posted. How can I do so?

Comment: using FCM notifications. There is an API, which you can trigger from your backend to send a push notification.

Comment: can you tell me which API? I am a beginner to android development. So can you provide a link where I can get to learn this thing?

Comment: you may get help from these [Firebase Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/) . You can also get tutorial regarding the same from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).  I personally use [OneSignal Notification service](https://onesignal.com/).

Comment: Is there any way to check that any new data is added to the url? I am using volley to read json data from server, and I want to send notification when there is any new data.

Answer (score 2):

You can try having a application check the url for new data, and if data is new use FCM to send a push notification to all your android users

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Thank you so much. This seems to be a good way. I will try this.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I check if there is any new data added? I am using volley to parse data.